# REST method calling @async

Tags: java, spring, asynchronous

I have a rest service that does a huge file download. I do not want the user to wait till the file download completes, rather the user makes the rest call and I return back a message to user saying "file download at /tmp/ in progress".

I have a service implemented with @async method that does the file download. Once the file download is complete I want to call other code (publish success message on kafka). I am unable to hook this part of code. Where do I place the code that runs after the @async method finishes execution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming this is Spring? 
Your method can return a [CompletableFuture](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html) wrapper of your return type. Look at the [Spring docs](https://spring.io/guides/gs/async-method/) that describe this.

You can then use the `then`-prefixed methods of `CompletableFuture` to attach a callback function for the result when it's available. There are some good examples [here](http://www.baeldung.com/java-completablefuture).

In your case it might look something like this :

```
@Async
public CompletableFuture<FileDownloadResult> myDownloadFileAsync(...) {
    // download the file and create the result..
    return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(result);
}

...

CompletableFuture<FileDownloadResult> future = myDownloadFileAsync(...);
 
future.thenAccept(res -> {
    // do things with the file download result
    publishToKafka(...);
});

future.get();
```

Comment: thank you. doing more google search i actually hit both of the tutorials that you mentioned :)